# Convert datetime format to time format inside the where clause to compare with another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named **orders** and **urgent_orders**. I need to get the all orders purchased, from **orders** table in specific *dates* which matches with *dates* in **urgent_orders** table.The problem is that the *dates* purchased in the **orders** table is in `datetime` format and *dates* in **Urgent_orders** are in `date` format.So when i compare the *date* in **orders** table and **urgent_orders** table i got nothing because in **orders** table it stores *time* too. So please tell me a way to format `datetime` to `date` with in the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from  orders inner join urgent_orders on(DATE(orders.date ) = urgent_orders.date )
```

Comment: check my query--> "select o.orders_id, o.customers_name, greatest(o.date_purchased, ifnull(o.last_modified, 0)) as date_last_modified, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total from  o inner join u on(DATE(o.date_purchased)=u.urgent_delivery_date) " . TABLE_URGENT_DELIVERY . " u, " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o, " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot, " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s, " . TABLE_DISMISS . " d where o.orders_id = ot.orders_id and ot.class = 'ot_total' and o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' order by date_last_modified desc limit 6";

Comment: pls chck query-> "select o.orders_id, o.customers_name, greatest(o.date_purchased, ifnull(o.last_modified, 0)) as date_last_modified, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total from  orders inner join urgent_orders on(DATE(o.date_purchased)=u.urgent_delivery_date) " . TABLE_URGENT_DELIVERY . " u, " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o, " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot, " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s, " . TABLE_DISMISS . " d where o.orders_id = ot.orders_id and ot.class = 'ot_total' and o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' order by date_last_modified desc limit 6"

Comment: both does not working. got syntax error near " . TABLE_URGENT_DELIVERY . " u, " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o, " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot, " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS .....

Comment: Thanks @shoaib for the selection

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code :

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`orders`.`date`) as `Order Date`,
FROM `orders`
```

Do the same thing to **Urgent_Orders** Table

Answer (score 0):

this will do it-->
"select o.orders_id, o.customers_name, greatest(o.date_purchased, ifnull(o.last_modified, 0)) as date_last_modified, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o, " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot, " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s where o.orders_id NOT IN (".$string_dismissed.") and o.orders_id = ot.orders_id and ot.class = 'ot_total' and o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and `DATE(o.date_purchased)` in (".$string_dates.") order by date_last_modified desc limit 6" ;